# Receiving null in servlet

Tags: java, android, google-app-engine, servlets, java-ee-7

```
public class PrimeServerSideServlet extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Override
    public void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
        throws IOException {
        processRequest(req, resp);

        String user = req.getParameter("id0");

        int primeNumberCounter = 1;
        long upperLimit = 10000000;
        //resp.setContentType("text/plain");
        PrintWriter writer = resp.getWriter();

        while (++i <= upperLimit) {

            long i1 = (long) Math.ceil(Math.sqrt(i));
            boolean isPrimeNumber = false;
            while (i1 > 1) {
                if ((i != i1) && (i % i1 == 0)) {
                    isPrimeNumber = false;
                    break;
                } else if (!isPrimeNumber) {
                    isPrimeNumber = true;
                }

                --i1;
            }

            if (isPrimeNumber) {
                writer.write(String.valueOf(i));
                writer.write("\n");
                ++primeNumberCounter;
            }

            writer.flush();
        }
        writer = resp.getWriter();
        writer.write("value" + user);
    } 
    private void processRequest(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)throws IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }
    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws IOException {
        doPost(req, resp);
    }
}
```

**Android Side code**

```
private String s;
EditText numDisplay;
Button calculateNow;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    numDisplay= (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    calculateNow = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
    //s=numDisplay.toString();  
    calculateNow.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            {

                new MyAsyncTask().execute(numDisplay.getText().toString());     

            } }
     } );
}
private class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, Double>{
        protected Double doInBackground(String... params) {

            postData(params[0]);
            return null;
        }
        protected void onPostExecute(Double result){
            //pb.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "command sent", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress){
            //pb.setProgress(progress[0]);
        }
        public void postData(String valueIWantToSend) {
            // Create a new HttpClient and Post Header
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://localhost:8888");

            try {
                // Add your data
                List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("id0", valueIWantToSend));
                httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

                // Execute HTTP Post Request
                HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            }
        }}}
```

Sending an integer value from android side using post and from servlet side  calculating prime number for the value user entered .

But I am getting null value when printing the value of user in servlet.I used post method on both side android and server I was getting error"http get is not support by this url",I changed servlet side code getting value through get method and calling post method in get.

I was sending my data through post and request type was get eventhough I was using post.I google a lot for this context but didn't got any solution .
I am not getting the response only sending request.Any help appreciated.

Comment: Nit: add `@Override` to your `doGet` method, to ensure that you really are overriding the method to handle GET requests..

Comment: Still getting the same issue

Comment: Is there a way where you can inspect the request to see whether the value is being passed. I dont know android. But what i meant normally in the browser we can check the request, same way is there a way for you

Comment: Yes from android side I get confirmation message that value is being sent but on servlet side i get null value.Secondly I am sending my request through post method but for request type get is being shown.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to send data from android to google app engine web app made in java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31808126/how-to-send-data-from-android-to-google-app-engine-web-app-made-in-java)

Comment: please do not create duplicate questions with exact same code. whats wrong with the other one you posted too?